# Laravel Artisan::queue infinite loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, laravel-queue

I have a defined a **Laravel Command** that runs via a cron job and everything is OK.
I need this command to be triggered by admin user and so I have created a controller which puts the execution of the command in queue by using

> `Artisan::queue('name:of-console-command')`

The job is executed successfully by queue worker, but after finishing it is not being remove from `jobs` table. It keeps staying there until `max-tries` number is achieved and then is inserted in `failed_jobs` table.

My Laravel version is **5.7**.

Has anyone experienced something like that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you give the command code?

Comment: @albus_severus i don't think that the code of console command is important. The console command finished and when you run it from command line it stops executing after finishing so there isn't any infinite loop in command. The problem is only when it is called as Artisan::queue

Comment: Something is causing your queue worker to believe that the process is incomplete.  This is usually from one of several things: a long process that exceeds the current timeout, an error in the script, or exiting the script prematurely (e.g., `dd($something)`).  This is why it would be helpful to see the code.

Comment: @matticustard thank you for the hint. There was a repository method called in the command which then executed another Artisan::call added from a colleague made the command run longer that it was expected. Switched other Artisan::call to Artisan::queue and everything is ok. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events#manually-accessing-the-queue

Since you are manually managing the job, you also need to remove it yourself, once the job is completed. Using `InteractsWithQueue` will give you access to a `delete` method.

Comment: I'm not manually managing job. I am just dispatching a console command just like it is specified in laravel documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands